# Why does the Linux kernel panic pin the CPU at 100%?

Tags: linux-kernel, panic

Take a look at the following:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel /boot/vmlinuz-linux
```

This will cause a kernel panic, as expected (there is no init). Much less expected is that it causes one processor core to spin until qemu is killed. Why is this? What exactly causes the kernel to leave the CPU in this state?

Comment: Should be asked on superuser, stackoverflow is more for programmers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does the Linux kernel panic pin the CPU at 100%?

This loop https://code.woboq.org/linux/linux/kernel/panic.c.html#74 :

```
while (1)
    cpu_relax();
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know why exactly this is done this way? What exactly is the risk if the kernel as a program was to simply finish execution?

Comment: `why exactly this is done this way?` why not? `What exactly is the risk if the kernel as a program was to simply finish execution?` Data corruption? Data deletion?

Comment: "Data corruption? Data deletion?": I forgot about the hardware needing time to finish work like syncing to disk. Thank you.

Comment: No, this is not what I meant. Continuing execution after a kernel panic _may_ execute some code never intended to run in such circumstances. Thus, it _may_ jump to an instruction that happens to format your whole hard drive. Predictable stop is way better than unpredictable.

Comment: When I said finish execution, I meant it in the sense of stopping execution, not continuing wherever it was before.

Comment: Essentially what I do not understand is why use a busy loop. Are there no other safe, less intensive alternatives are available to the kernel during a panic?

Comment: There is no "stopping execution instruction", it does not exist. CPU has to do "something", clock is still ticking. Kernel has to do "something", it does a busy loop, it can't do anything else. You could turn off the power, but: it requires some hardware specific communication, and it may not work, and it may panic during that communication and turning off will not allow admins to read the kernel panic on their screen. A busy loop is the safest and the simplest. It's a _panic_.